# How do I extract all article links from BBC RSS feed using Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, rss

I tried this, it doesn't seem to be working. I only need the article links in a list.

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/entertainment_and_arts/rss.xml")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(),"html.parser");

for link in bsObj.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though it renders as HTML when accessed through a browser, the server returns an XML to Python. If you `print(html.read())` you will see that XML.

In this XML the `<a>` tags are replaced with `<link>` tags (with no attributes), so you need to change your code to reflect that:

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = urlopen("http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/entertainment_and_arts/rss.xml")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(),"html.parser");

for link in bsObj.find_all('link'):
    print(link.text)

#  http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/
#  http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/
#  http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-41914725
#  http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-41886207
#  http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-41886475
#  ...
#  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import feedparser
url='http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/entertainment_and_arts/rss.xml'
data = feedparser.parse(url)
i=0
while i < len(data):
    print(data['entries'][i]["link"])
    i=i+1
```